# Why stringizing operator is only accepted as a macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

I tried to use the `#` operator in my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello %s !!! n", #world);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc, this codes gives the following error:

```
str.c: In function ‘main’:
str.c:5:27: error: stray ‘#’ in program
  printf("hello %s !!! n", #world);
```

But, when I define a macro that uses this operator, the code is compiled:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello %s \n", STRINGIFY(world));
    return 0;
}
```

Is this error reported by the pre-processor? If so, why?

Comment: Because it is how it is defined. Outside of the macro you can very well suround it with `""`

Comment: @EugeneSh., Isn't gonna be the string literal `"#world"` in that case?

Comment: In which case? `STRINGIFY(world)` will expand into `"world"`.

Comment: Is what error reported by the pre-processor?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons this error `error: stray ‘#’ in program`. In the second case the output of `gcc -E ...` gives `printf("hello %s \n", "world");`, which means the pre-processor expanded `STRINGIFY(world)` by `"world"`. So in the firstcase, the pre-processor didn't expanded the `#` operator, right?

Comment: Correct, the preprocessor did not expand the first one because it did not invoke a preprocessor macro.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I thought that you were talking about surrounding `#world` with `""` in the first code.

Comment: I meant that the use-case in your example does not justify permitting this notation. I can't come up with any that does.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I was doing some experiments :-).

Answer (score 3):

Because `#parameter` is the part of **macro** expansion. All this is done by a preprocessor before the compiler even sees the code. And this token is applied to macro parameters only.
Consider the following macro:

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

`Str(Hello)` is `"Hello"`

But if we write #word in the code the preprocessor does not see this as a part of a macro and **word** is not a macro parameter. Thus the preprocessor ignores it. The compiler sees the same #word and knows nothing what to do with it. So it reports an error. Consider the following text worked out by a preprocessor.

```
#define STR(x) #x
const char * str=STR(Hello);
const char * buggy_str=#Hello;
```

The result will be:

```
const char * str="Hello";
const char * buggy_str=#Hello;
```

The C compiler sees the first string and it is ok for him. But when he sees the second string, he knows nothing about the token `#` and thus reports an error.

Answer (score 3):

The `#` character is only allowed in a C program inside:

1. Comments
2. String and character literals
3. Preprocessor directives

It is defined this way by the C standard.

In your program it is found outside of any of these contexts, so it is flagged as "stray", and the program is rejected.

The C standard doesn't specify which translation phases are responsible for diagnostics. They are only conceptual phases anyway, and may or may not be identifiable in a real compiler. So the question of whether the error is emitted during preprocessing is not well defined.